# 3 wires but no ground terminal

Tags: outlet

I have an underground electric cable coming in to my detached garage. It has three wires red, black and white. I don't see a bare copper ground wire. Here are the multimeter readings.

(order: Multimeter common to Red)

1. white to black 120 V
2. red to black 40 V
3. white to red 1 V

From this, I can infer that black is hot wire. Way could explain 2 to give out 40v? What are the red and white wires for?

Comment: Does the wire enter the garage in a buried metallic conduit? I don't know if it's to code (or what the code is where you live) but the conduit itself could be the ground connection.

Comment: While the conduit should itself be grounded, it is not to be relied upon as a safety ground.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a 220V split feed, using what appears to be an old-style 'dryer' connection without a ground. Further, based on what you said here, there is a fault on the red wire. **It is not safe. Turn off the breaker to the feed and call an electrician.**

What the wires are supposed to be:

- White is neutral, and should measure no more than 3V to ground (without a load, 0V.)
- Black is L1 hot leg, and should measure 120V to white and 240V to red.
- Red is L2 hot leg, and should measure 120 to white and 240V to black.

What you’re measuring on red is an **open (floating) wire**, which has some coupling to the energized black lead. That’s why you see 40V or so. If you connect a load like a lamp between red and white, the voltage will drop to zero.

So you have a open somewhere on the red lead. It could be due to a break in the wire, a failed breaker at the panel, or some other issue. Being a buried cable, which is clearly old and now not up to code, I would be very suspicious of the cable's condition.

Regardless, you should upgrade it to a 4-wire feed with a grounded sub-panel at your garage (as in, grounded with an actual earthing rod) because it's a detached structure. The electrician will advise you on this.

Comment: Just to be clear (and I know you know this, hacktastical) the ground wire must come from the main panel. The ground rod is connected to the same green wire (that comes from the main panel). In the garage, the green ground and white neutral are not connected together.

Answer (score 1):

Voltmeter measurements may be confusing *if* one of the conductors is floating. Then you pick-up some voltage that has been induced through capacitance from an adjacent wire in the cable. Otherwise (not considering unlikely phase difference) the numbers should add up and they don't!

Word of caution: Perhaps you should hire an electrician!

I know that you wouldn't be asking a question here if that was on your mind.
So if you promise not to get electrocuted I would recommend:

- Find the opposite end of the cable and inspect there.
- Alternatively try a lamp with an incandescent lightbulb instead of the voltmeter. That may confirm if one of the wires is unconnected (floating).
  The two wires where the light bulb will be lit are likely live and neutral. If you won't get the lightbulb on in either combination then the wire is unconnected.

Comment: It seems likely that the black wire is continuous power, intended for outlets, and the red wire is switched power, intended for lights.

Answer (score 0):

Your profile shows that you are residing in the US.

Wiring colour code applicable in the US:

Black - L1

Red   - L2

White - Neutral

Voltages:

Between black & white - 120V

Between red & white - 120V

Between black & red - 240V

It would be advisable to check the voltages at the other end to rule out a wire-break or breaker-off.